# How to get first 4 digits from an integer column in python

Tags: python, pandas, string, datetime

I am trying to get and month from the column which is integer format

```
'''dvd['yy'] = str(dvd['CalendarYearMonth'])[:3]
dvd['mon'] = str(dvd['CalendarYearMonth'])[4:6]'''
```

but getting following output

```
   CalendarYearMonth CountryCode  Dividends   yy mon
0             202108          CN      196.0  0     2
1             202109          CN      380.0  0     2
2             202108          IN        NaN  0     2
3             202109          IN      115.0  0     2
```

could anyone help me to get the correct output- dvd is the input DF

Comment: for you want int or sting as output? For int, check [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69119083/16343464)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
dvd['yy'] = dvd['CalendarYearMonth'].astype(str).str[:3]
dvd['mon'] = dvd['CalendarYearMonth'].astype(str).str[4:6]
```

Comment: thanks it worked, very simple but I am not clear why second str was required

Comment: @Ashish Happy to help :P The reason the extra `.str` is needed is because it's still a pandas series, you need to access the str accessor :)

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
dvd = pd.DataFrame( {
    'CalendarYearMonth': [202108.0, 202109.0, 202108.0, 202109.0],

})
dvd['yy'] = dvd['CalendarYearMonth'].apply(lambda x : str(x)[:4])
dvd['mon'] = dvd['CalendarYearMonth'].apply(lambda x : str(x)[4:6])
print(DVD)
```

Output:

```
CalendarYearMonth   yy      mon
0   202108.0        2021    08
1   202109.0        2021    09
2   202108.0        2021    08
3   202109.0        2021    09
```

Answer (score 1):

If the date is already an int, take advantage of it

```
df['yy'] = df['CalendarYearMonth']//100
df['mon'] = df['CalendarYearMonth']-df['yy']*100
```

output:

```
   CalendarYearMonth CountryCode  Dividends    yy  mon
0             202108          CN      196.0  2021    8
1             202109          CN      380.0  2021    9
2             202108          IN        NaN  2021    8
3             202109          IN      115.0  2021    9
```

Comment: smart way without knowing any special function, i like such solutions

Comment: Or:  `dvd['mon'] = dvd['CalendarYearMonth'] % 100`

Answer (score 1):

To bring up one more option, you can convert the column with dates to datetime objects and then extract the year and month information:

```
import pandas as pd

dvd = pd.DataFrame({
    'CalendarYearMonth': [201908, 202001, 202103, 202107],
})

dates = pd.to_datetime(dvd['CalendarYearMonth'], format='%Y%m')
dvd['yy'] = dates.dt.year
dvd['mon'] = dates.dt.month
```

It gives:

```
   CalendarYearMonth    yy  mon
0             201908  2019    8
1             202001  2020    1
2             202103  2021    3
3             202107  2021    7
```